# Jackson: deserialization to a collection

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have this specific problem with JSON deserialization. Let's have this JSON structure:

```
{
  "header":{
    "objects":[
      {"field":"value1"},
      {"field":"value2"}
    ]
  }
}
```

The JSON structure can't be altered as it comes from a 3rd party system.

Now let's have this simple POJO:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=PojoDeserializer.class)
public class Pojo {
    private string field;

    //...getter, setter
}
```

The mentioned PojoDeserializer takes {"field": "value"} json string and deserializes it to the Pojo instance. So I can simply do the deserialization like this

> Pojo instance = new
>   ObjectMapper().readValue("{\"field\":
>   \"value\"}", Pojo.class);

And here's my problem. Let's have another deserializer PojosCollectionDeserializer which takes the mentioned structure and deserializes it to a Collection of Pojo instances. I'd like to use it in a similar fashion as in the previous example:

```
Collection<Pojo> pojos = new ObjectMapper().readValue("{...}", Collection.class);
```

But this doesn't work as there is not defined that Collection should be created using the PojosCollectionDeserializer. Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why are trying to explicitly specify deserializers, as it would all work just fine with something like:

```
public class Message {
    public Header header; // or, if you prefer, getter and setter
}
public class Header {
    public List<Pojo> objects;
}
public class Pojo {
    public String field;
}

Message msg = objectMapper.readValue(json, Message.class);
```

without any additional configuration or annotations. There is no need to construct custom serializers or deserializers for simple cases like this.

Comment: How does Jackson know to instantiate `Pojo` instances for the `List<Pojo> objects;` collection?  With runtime type erasure, I'm not sure how it would be able to do that.  Any insights?

Comment: Type erasure is actually not 100% complete: class declarations do retain generic type information for method and field declarations, as well as for subtype ("extends Xxx") declarations -- this is where Jackson finds content type. Problem occurs when passing Class objects; there is just List.class, and no "List<Pojo>.class" thanks to type erasure.